# When using proxy_pass, can /etc/hosts be used to resolve domain names instead of "resolver"?

Tags: url-rewriting, nginx, reverse-proxy

Can **/etc/hosts** be used instead of **resolver** when using **proxy_pass**?

I need to perform a proxy_pass to the same nginx machine. Is there a way to resolve the domains using the machine's /etc/hosts file instead of specifying a DNS server thru the "resolver" property?

This will save me the additional hops needed to reach the same server. I have tried setting up the internal IP mapped to the DNS in /etc/hosts file but nginx is still reading from the DNS server set in the **resolver** property. Or is there a way to make the HTTPProxy module to consider the /etc/hosts file settings?

Thanks for any advice you could share..

This is the same question I posted in the nginx forum:
http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?11,218997

Comment: The strange thing , this is working if you use upstream (host resolution)

Comment: Upstream worked for me as well, it's a bit of extra code but it seems cleaner than some of the other methods listed below.

Comment: It also possible to workaround with systemd-resolved if using a server with systemd. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64909236/153718

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can get around this by installing `dnsmasq` and setting your resolver to `127.0.0.1`. Basically this uses your local DNS as a resolver, but it only resolves what it knows about (among those things is your `/etc/hosts`) and forwards the rest to your default DNS.

Comment: But sadly `dnsmasq` does not automatically detect changes in `hosts` file. You have to send `HUP`.

Comment: Can you give more details on how we should setup dnsmasq in order to get our nginx to resolve the other container dns name properly ? just installing dnsmasq and adding extra_hosts: - "container_name:127.0.0.1" to my docker-compose.yml config didn't resolve the issue

Comment: If you are using docker I think DNS works a little bit different, especially if you're doing container to container communication. Check out the [docker networking configuration](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/) for more info.

Comment: Will this work with other *nix flavors (Rasbian specifically) that don't have proxy_pass?

Answer (score 5):

A workaround is to use Nginx map, in order to copy the `/etc/hosts` content.

```
map $wanted_host $wanted_host_ip
{
    default 127.0.0.1;
    b.dev.local X.X.X.X;
    a.dev.local X.X.X.X;
}

server
{
    listen              80;
    server_name         ~^(?P<wanted_port>[0-9]+?)-(?P<wanted_host>.+?)\.HOSTNAME$;

    location /
    {
        proxy_pass http://$wanted_host_ip:$wanted_port;

    }
}
```

This will map `wanted_host`to `wanted_host_ip` , like a resolver.

Comment: Would this work if has multiple (sub)domains, where just an IP is not enough to know which virtual server to hit?

Comment: Sure, you could use domain as X.X.X.X, if it resolves.