# nginx proxy_pass to a linked docker container

Tags: nginx, docker, reverse-proxy

I have two docker containers with nginx. container1 is linked to container2. Docker then adds an entry to */etc/hosts* which I entered into the nginx configuration like so:

```
server {
    location ~ ^/some_url/(.*)$ {
        proxy_pass http://container1/$1;
    }
}
```

I can ping *container1* from *container2*, but nginx cannot resolve it:

> *1 no resolver defined to resolve container1

How can I proxy_pass a request to another docker container?

Comment: Can you share your hosts file? How did you link the two containers? (What name does the link have?) Also gotcha: In case you `rm`d one of the containers and restart it later, the IP will have changed (hosts are not updated)

Comment: I just tried configuration similar to yours and it worked fine for me with `nginx:1.7.9`. Can you start bash at *container2* and curl *container1* ? You are not using the same configurations both container1 and 2, are you?

Comment: @MykolaGurov I can ping and curl and what not container1 from container2. My problem is, that nginx doesn't seem to be able to resolve it. I'm not using the same configurations, no (if you're referring to nginx config).

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Use an upstream block instead of the container name directly

```
upstream backend {
    server container1;
}
server {
    location ~ ^/some_url/(.*)$ {
        proxy_pass http://backend/$1;
    }
}
```

This should allow normal name resolution to occur providing a way to easily use docker links with nginx.

Comment: Best answer when you aren't wanting to mess around with any external dependencies.

Comment: The problem I had with this solution is that `container1` must be up and running before you can start your nginx container, otherwise it won't start

Comment: Write a script that waits until the backend is up. Something like this should work: `bash -c "while ! curl -s container1:8080 > /dev/null; do echo waiting for container1; sleep 3; done; start_nginx.sh"` where `start_nginx.sh` actually starts the nginx service.

Comment: @Marc-AlexandreBérubé Shouldn't be an issue though - if you're using `--link` that's a requirement anyhow.

Comment: only really clean and safe solution. kudos!

Comment: Does not work, throws the same error with the upstream name defined. Alpine image nginx/1.23.2

Answer (score 51):

I believe, Nginx is using its own DNS resolver implementation,

You could use embedded Docker DNS service, if enabled, check your container resolver:

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf
```

Should be:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.11
```

Use this IP as resolver:

```
server {
    location ~ ^/some_url/(.*)$ {
        resolver 127.0.0.11;
        proxy_pass http://container1/$1;
    } }
```

---

There is plenty of Docker image with such hack in the entrypoint:

https://github.com/jetbrains-infra/docker-nginx-resolver

entrypoint.sh:

```
...
echo resolver $(awk 'BEGIN{ORS=" "} $1=="nameserver" {print $2}' /etc/resolv.conf) ";" > /etc/nginx/includes/resolver.conf
...
```

nginx.conf:

```
http {
    include       /etc/nginx/includes/resolver.conf;
....
```

Comment: Hmm, maybe the hard coded IP 127.0.0.11 could bring some issues

Comment: I think yes. The ideal way would be to parse the `etc/resolv.conf` for the nameserver IP.

Comment: I just came across this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35744650/docker-network-nginx-resolver#comment68472082_37656784. Hardcoding IP address in user-defined networks won't be a problem.

Comment: Why Nginx dont parse resolv.conf btw ?

Comment: It looks like it does but not sure why it specifically fails in the case of docker.

Comment: Maybe resolv.conf is changed after the image is started, hence nginx didnt get it

Comment: I am running nginx in kubernetes.  cat: /etc/resolve.conf: No such file or directory

Comment: for future google visitors looking for a solution in openshift: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66857955/1143392

Comment: What's the point of having the nameserver set in /etc/resolv.conf if you hardcode the 127.0.0.11 in the nginx conf? SO is full of questions about this issue but there is still no answer other than hardcoding that sucks because the config becomes docker-specific. There is no answer why ping works but nginx does not. And this answer just puts together two random advices with no explanation.

Comment: I agree, I really prefer answer with real explanation, but here, nginx have its own resolver implementation, you can make a PR on nginx code source, or use the hack (ex: https://github.com/jetbrains-infra/docker-nginx-resolver )

Answer (score 9):

You should take a look at this answer about using /etc/hosts as your resolver: [Using /etc/hosts as resolver for url rewriting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305015/when-using-proxy-pass-can-etc-hosts-be-used-to-resolve-domain-names-instead-of/8559797#8559797)

Basically, your dns or resolver does not use /etc/hosts to resolve names during a lookup, but you can work around this by installing `dnsmasq` and using `127.0.0.1` as your resolver. You can add 127.0.0.1 as the resolver directly in your nginx config:

```
server {
    location ~ ^/some_url/(.*)$ {
        resolver 127.0.0.1;
        proxy_pass http://container1/$1;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's something I actually already tried, but since dnsmasq did not start up without errors I gave up. Maybe too quickly. Will try again and let you know.

Comment: I tried again, simply added dnsmasq to my entrypoint. If you're running your container inside a VM make sure to run dnsmasq as root, it won't work otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it seem that using `$request_uri` get me this error. So I finally use this and Docker resolver is taken

```
server {
    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://backend/api/;
    }
}
```