# nginx location regular expression

Tags: regex, nginx

can some one please help me with location regex.
I have such url: https://host.com:444/aaaa-bbb-63810-host1.my-network.com
And I need to extract values: 63810 and 1 (part of host1)

what I'm trying is:

```
    location ~* ^/aaaa-bbb-(?<port>\d+)-host(?<host_id>\d+)/ {
        proxy_pass              http://machine$host_id.my-stg.com:$port;
    }
```

But this is not going to work. What I've missed?

Comment: i think you need to remove the last forward slash.

Comment: At least you need `resolver`

Comment: Is it possible to configure nginx to use hosts?

Comment: No, not directly. But there is at least one workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305015/when-using-proxy-pass-can-etc-hosts-be-used-to-resolve-domain-names-instead-of/8559797#8559797