# proxy_pass does not resolve DNS using /etc/hosts

Tags: nginx, lua, dns, hosts, hosts-file

In nginx the `proxy_pass` directive is not resolving DNS using the `/etc/hosts` file. Any way to enable this possibility (maybe by leveraging Lua as a last resort)?

Answer (score 8):

If you have a server with systemd you can use the nameserver shipped with it, systemd-resolved, to resolve your hostnames from the `/etc/hosts` file.

Just add this to your nginx config `http`, `server` or `location` block:

```
resolver 127.0.0.53;
```

Use `systemctl status systemd-resolved.service` to see if it is running on your server.

Answer (score 5):

In short, you need to install dnsmasq locally and use 127.0.0.1 as a resolver.

See this related question and answer:

[When using proxy_pass, can /etc/hosts be used to resolve domain names instead of "resolver"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305015/when-using-proxy-pass-can-etc-hosts-be-used-to-resolve-domain-names-instead-of)