# NGINX configuration resolver not working for local host

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2

I have deployed my project(angular) on nginx its running  on port 4210. I am using AWS ec2 instance. when I am trying to run my project on browser its giving me 500 internal server error.Can you please tell me where I am going wrong this is my first time.Thank You in advance

`nginx -t` is giving success and angular server is also working

**Default server configuration(sites-available)**

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        listen 127.0.0.1;
        proxy_connect_timeout       600s;
        proxy_send_timeout          600s;
        proxy_read_timeout          600s;
        send_timeout                600s;
        set $frontend "http://localhost:4210";
        set $apiBackend "http://localhost:5002";

        root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {

                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                proxy_pass $frontend/$uri$is_args$args;
                proxy_redirect off;
        }

        location /api {

                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                proxy_pass $apiBackend/$uri$is_args$args;
                proxy_redirect off;
        }

   }
```

**my nginx.conf file**

```
  user www-data;
     worker_processes auto;
     pid /run/nginx.pid;
     include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

     events {
         worker_connections 768;
         # multi_accept on;
     }

     http {
        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##enter code here

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;
        resolver 127.0.0.1;
        
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
     }
```

logs

> 2019/09/05 18:47:47 [error] 7090#7090: send() failed (111: Connection refused) while resolving, resolver: 127.0.0.1:53

> 2019/09/05 18:47:47 [error] 7090#7090: send() failed (111: Connection refused) while resolving, resolver: 127.0.0.1:53

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here're some options to solve that:

1. Install dnsmasq: `sudo apt-get install dnsmasq` to have local DNS server running on `127.0.0.1` (similar to [1])
2. Update nginx config and set `resolver 169.254.169.253` to use default AWS DNS server for EC2 instances in VPC [2]

Here's a link to AWS knowledge center regarding dnsmasq [3]

[1] https://stackoverflow.com/a/8559797/1224211
[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-dns.html#vpc-dns-support.
[3] https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/dns-resolution-failures-ec2-linux/