# Certbot DNS problem - not using /etc/hosts

Tags: dns, raspberry-pi, lets-encrypt, certbot

I am trying to install a certificate using `certbot` from LetsEncrypt on a Raspberry Pi.  I have installed Apache2 and created a webserver at http://subdomain.mydomain.com on the Raspberry Pi.  The `certbot` command obtains a certificate and writes it to http://subdomain.mydomain.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/<etc.>

*Background Info: I am doing this because I need a local server to address IoT devices and my Ajax calls are failing because I am not allowed to mix http with https.  The IoT devices are incapable of a hosting a webserver with SSL - they use a simple http:/192.168.1.xx/`<string>`* format

I don't want to create a DNS entry at my registrar/ISP because I am trying to create a scalable solution and creating hundreds (perhaps thousands if we do well) of subdomain entries there is impractical.  Creating my own DNS server is a possibility, but I would rather just do it all on the Pi - my bash installation script will take care of everything (once I get it to work!).

I tried first to create an entry into the local hosts (/etc/hosts) file which looks like this:

```
   127.0.0.1       localhost
   ::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
   ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
   ff02::2         ip6-allrouters

   127.0.1.1       SubDomain
   192.168.1.111   subdomain.mydomain.com
```

This works for commands like `ping`, but not for `nslookup` or `dig` and definitely not for `certbot`.  The `certbot` command finds my main server - DNS is configured with a * to go to my Public IP for all unknown subdomains:

```
  A       *         xx.xx.xx.xx //My public IP address
```

So then I installed `dnsmasq` (See: [When using proxy_pass, can /etc/hosts be used to resolve domain names instead of "resolver"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305015/when-using-proxy-pass-can-etc-hosts-be-used-to-resolve-domain-names-instead-of)) and followed the configuration options shown here: [How to Setup a Raspberry Pi DNS Server](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-dns-server/)

However, that doesn't work either.  `certbot` still looks at my main (external DNS) and finds my Public (wildcard) IP.  Here's a summary of the changes made in /etc/dnsmasq.conf

```
domain-needed ## enabled
bogus-priv ## enabled
no-resolv ## enabled
server=8.8.8.8 ## added (#server=/localnet/192.168.0.1 left as is)
server=8.8.4.4 ## added
cache-size=1500 ##increased from 150
```

How can I force certbot to find and use my local/private IP 192.168.1.111?  Any alternative solutions using scripts/redirection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved my problem but I abandoned LetsEncrypt entirely.  The answer was not in DNS, but in approaching it from a completely different angle. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60516812/989468) was pretty much 95% of the solution.

**Important!** This only works if you have control over the browser.  We do, since it is for our kiosk application which runs in a browser.

Step 1: Become your own CA

Step 2: Sign your SSL certificate as a CA

Step 3: Import the signed CA (.pem file) into the browser (under Authorities)

Step 4:  Point your Apache conf file to the local SSL (the process generates .key and .crt files for this as well).

Answer (score 0):

Create a wildcard certificate using Let's Encrypt DNS validation. You will then have to renew the certificate manually. Otherwise, your server must be on the public Internet with correct DNS settings.

Comment: I'm doing that now, but that involves renewing the certificate every three months - that's again impractical with 100s of installations.

Comment: @Chiwda - then your objective is not possible. You must either have public DNS records or manually create the certificate. Your comment of creating a DNS server won't work as it would have to be public also. That is how Let's Encrypt validates you control the domain.

Comment: Bind can be installed on Private IP addresses: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-bind-as-a-private-network-dns-server-on-ubuntu-14-04  I am considering that, although it is getting pretty heavy/complicated

Comment: You can install bind on a private IP address and create private DNS zones. That will not help you with Let's Encrypt. Let's Encrypt will only communicate with the **Authoritative Name Servers** for your domain. Those servers must be public.